# Why other javaScript functions cannot read a div that is made with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am currently working on a project where I should manipulate single page content using JavaScript. That is, I just have to manipulate a single HTML page with JavaScript and I have no chance to create any other HTML page. That's why I want to make a div using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const emaildetails = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('id','email-details');
  document.body.append(emaildetails);
  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = sendmail;
  /*const emaildetails = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('id','email-details');
  document.body.append(emaildetails);*/
  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
  
});
```

Here, `emaildetails` declares the div called **email-details**. However, the **email-details** div is not accessible to other Javascript functions of my code. The function bellow reads null at div **email-details**,

```js
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#email-details').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
  localStorage.clear();
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
    // Print emails
    console.log(emails);
    emails.forEach(email => display_mailbox(email,mailbox));
  });
  //display_mailbox(emails, mailbox);
  
}
```

It shows the following error. What is going on actually!
[image]

Here, inbox.js:13 is `load_mailbox('inbox')` in the DOM Loader and inbox.js:60 is the `document.querySelector('#email-details').style.display = 'none';` in `load_mailbox(mailbox)` function.
I am a beginner at javascript.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

> Return value
> `undefined`.

So that's the value of

> ```
> const emaildetails = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('id','email-details');
> ```

You should rather write

```
const emaildetails = document.createElement('div');
emaildetails.setAttribute('id','email-details');
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you defer the script in html file or place it at the end of the body tag? Probably your script is loading before that element load that's why you are getting this error. You can do this :

```
document.querySelector('#email-details')?.style.display = 'none';
```

to see if this is the problem